# No taints on kubernetes master node

Tags: kubernetes

Spec:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- kubernetes version: 1.21.1

As far as I know, there will be taints on master node by default (`node-role.kubernetes.io/master`). However, there is no taint on any master node on my cluster

```
root@master3:~# `kubectl get node `

`NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION`

`master1   Ready    control-plane,master   25h   v1.21.1`

`master2   Ready    control-plane,master   25h   v1.21.1`

`master3   Ready    control-plane,master   25h   v1.21.1`

`worker1   Ready    <none>                 25h   v1.21.1`

`worker2   Ready    <none>                 25h   v1.21.1`

root@master3:~# `kubectl describe node master | grep -i taints`

`Taints:             <none>`<p>
`Taints:             <none>`<p>
`Taints:             <none>`<p>
```

And some pods are scheduled on master node

```
root@master3:~# kubectl get pod -o wide | grep master <p>
nginx-test-5dbdb6f988-dfmcv   1/1     Running   0          23m   10.233.97.35    master1   <none>           <none><p>
nginx-test-5dbdb6f988-flm4h   1/1     Running   0          22m   10.233.97.36    master1   <none>           <none><p>
```

Here is the yaml for deployment nginx-test

```
root@master3:~# `kubectl get deployment nginx-test -o yaml`<p>
`apiVersion: apps/v1`<p>
`kind: Deployment`<p>
`metadata:`<p>
`  annotations:`<p>
`    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "10"`<p>
`  creationTimestamp: "2021-07-06T01:33:19Z"`<p>
`  generation: 23`<p>
`  labels:`<p>
`    app: nginx-test`<p>
`  name: nginx-test`<p>
`  namespace: default`<p>
`  resourceVersion: "175269"`<p>
`  uid: 4a08b870-1b31-4d66-b39f-d25c70e4e22d`<p>
`spec:`<p>
`  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600`<p>
`  replicas: 15`<p>
`  revisionHistoryLimit: 10`<p>
`  selector:`<p>
`    matchLabels:`<p>
`      app: nginx-test`<p>
`  strategy:`<p>
`    rollingUpdate:`<p>
`      maxSurge: 25%`<p>
`      maxUnavailable: 25%`<p>
`    type: RollingUpdate`<p>
`  template:`<p>
`    metadata:`<p>
`      annotations:`<p>
`        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: "2021-07-06T14:52:42+09:00"`<p>
`      creationTimestamp: null`<p>
`      labels:`<p>
`        app: nginx-test`<p>
`    spec:`<p>
`      containers:`<p>
`      - image: nginx`<p>
`        imagePullPolicy: Always`<p>
`        name: nginx`<p>
`        resources: {}`<p>
`        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log`<p>
`        terminationMessagePolicy: File`<p>
`      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst`<p>
`      restartPolicy: Always`<p>
`      schedulerName: default-scheduler`<p>
`      securityContext: {}`<p>
`      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30`<p>
`status:`<p>
`  availableReplicas: 15`<p>
`  conditions:`<p>
`  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-06T05:44:30Z"`<p>
`    lastUpdateTime: "2021-07-06T05:44:30Z"`<p>
`    message: Deployment has minimum availability.`<p>
`    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable`<p>
`    status: "True"`<p>
`    type: Available`<p>
`  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-06T01:33:19Z"`<p>
`    lastUpdateTime: "2021-07-06T06:03:41Z"`<p>
`    message: ReplicaSet "nginx-test-5dbdb6f988" has successfully progressed.`<p>
`    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable`<p>
`    status: "True"`<p>
`    type: Progressing`<p>
`  observedGeneration: 23`<p>
`  readyReplicas: 15`<p>
`  replicas: 15`<p>
`  updatedReplicas: 15`<p>
```

Comment: Hello @JAESANGPARK and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please check your Kubespray inventory file and see if your master node is in `kube-master` section and not for example in `kube-node`?

Answer (score 0):

Taints on control plane nodes are not required. It all depends on how you installed Kubernetes and how it wants things to be. Single node installers, for example, don't set them up or nothing would be able to run.

Comment: So, since I installed the Kubernetes with kubespray, then there is no Taints on my control plane nodes?

Then do you know why the other master node ( master2, master3 ) is not scheduled?

Comment: From the code (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/360aff4a571f4a8ac7603a4a68223e744fad1209/roles/kubernetes/control-plane/tasks/kubeadm-setup.yml#L188-L195) I think this means you had the same node marked as both control plane and worker? Not sure, but stare at that code until you understand it :)

Comment: After staring the code you gave me for a while, I got to know why this issue happened.
According to the code, the task will delete the taint of the items for the node in the inventory_hostname.
I found that I listed the master node on the [kube_node] which makes the task remove the taint on the master node.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @JAESANGPARK. Isn't that what I asked you to check in my previous comment? ;) I will post a separate answer reflecting that for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my previous comment, the issue was due to the fact that the master node was listed under the `[kube-node]` section of Kubespray inventory file instead of the proper `[kube-master]` section. That caused the taints to be removed. Putting the master node in the `[kube-master]` section will fix the problem.